# Choosing Component / External Power Supply & Arduino 3.3V

Tags: arduino, power-supply, components

I've made a prototype for a small music player using arduino pro mini 3.3v.

My question relates to powering the device.

I want to be able to use it outdoors, and eventually power it "straight from the mains" (there's an electrician who can help me later with this part) but right now I'm not sure what type of power input component I should be using for the Arduino. So far I've just been testing with a LiPo 3.7v.

Thanks so much for your help in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if your question should be closed because its unclear or off topic (shopping question).

Answer (score 1):

If power consumption is not a concern, simply use a 5V adapter and you'll be fine.

As long as you don't draw too much current, the onboard 3.3V regulator of the Pro Mini will do the trick.

Comment: Note that you must connect the 5V from the adapter to the RAW pin, and not to the VCC pin.

Answer (score 0):

Onboard regulator is only good for 150mA.

Wire up a 5V regulator

https://www.mpja.com/5-Volt-1A-Plug-Supply-ENG-3A-055WU05/productinfo/35398+PS/

and a 3.3V regulator

https://www.pololu.com/product/2097
or
https://www.pololu.com/product/2106

as 3.3V wallwarts don't seem to be a thing.